# C++ breaking string into new line after punctuation

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to learn strings and I've figured out how to replace as well as insert into an existing string. I have 3 strings at the moment which I've declared as constants, I've merged them into one string variable which puts them all one after eachother.

I've also changed every single occurance of "Hi" to "Bye" in those strings. My 3 strings bundled into a single one are as following: 
"Hi! My name is xxxx! I would like to be on my own but I don't know how to, could you help me?"

I want it to display as:
Hi!
My name is xxxx!
I would like to be on my own but I don't know how to, could you help me?

As soon as a puncutation occurs I'd like to insert a line break "\n", using replace works but that means the punctuation will disappear, using insert will first insert the line break before the punctuation, and it won't continue to the next one which results in:
"Hi!
My name is xxxx! I would like to be on my own but I don't know how to, could you help me?"

I changed the code to only include dots to simplify it, once solved the same solution can be applied to any other part such as question marks or exclamation marks.

Any tips on how to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string const Text0 = "Hi.";
string const Text1 = "My name is xxxx.";
string const Text2 = "I would like to be on my own but I don't know how to, could you help me.";
string const Text3 = "I would, but I don't know how to.";

string text = Text0 + Text1 + Text2 + Text3;

int main() {

    while (text.find("I") != string::npos) {
        text.replace(text.find("I"), 1, "J");

    }
    while (text.find("like") != string::npos) {
        text.replace(text.find("like"), 4, "milk");
    }

    text.insert(text.find("."), "\n");


    cout << text;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: insert is the tool for the job.  Please show your [mre] using it so we can help you getting it working.

Comment: *using replace works but that means the punctuation will disappear* -- Only if you coded it that way.  Revisit your assignment using pencil and paper and improve / change your design so that the punctuation will not disappear.  Once you see how to do that using pencil and paper, transfer those plans to code.

Comment: Hint for simple and a bit crude approach: you could replace `". "` with `".\n"`, and same for every other punctuation char you want to be replaced.

Comment: _"using insert will first insert the line break before the punctuation"_ - Just add one to the index where you insert?

Comment: Added the code to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own short function that will add newline after every punctuation sign.

For example:

```
void addNewLines(std::string *text)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < text->length(); i++)
    {
        if ((*text)[i] == '!' || (*text)[i] == '?' || (*text)[i] == '.')
        {
            (*text)[i + 1] = '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in this piece of code, in the for loop you are going from the first to the last character of the string, and after every punctuation sign you replace empty space with `\n` character.

I'm using pointers here to prevent copying of the string to the function, in case it is a huge string, but you could do it without pointers, that way syntax is a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without a new function? Trying to stick to just one function to handle it all. This does work however.

Comment: If you are not sure that there is empty space after punctuation sign you can add a check inside the if statement to check for that. Then if there is no empty space you could use insert() function to insert '\n' there, or manually split the string add the '\n' and copy it back. But doing it manually is not recommended because you already have insert() function to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to do it without the new function. Just put this for loop where you want it. And then without the new function you don't need pointers.

Comment: Alright, I got it working. However if I use "i + 1" it removes the first letter from the next word (As they are stuck together), if I just use i it removes the punctuation.

Comment: Yeah that's what I said in my first comment, if you know that you will not have empty space after the punctuation sign add another if statement inside the current one which will check `if ((*text)[i + 1] == ' ')` (checking if "i + 1" is empty space). If "i + 1" is empty space do this `(*text)[i + 1] = '\n';`, else, if "i + 1" is not an empty space then use insert() function. You will probably want to do something like this:  `text->insert(i, "\n")` (again, syntax is like this because I used pointer).

Comment: Hmm I might've gone a backward approach here. But seeing as every new sentence start with a capital letter I added 
"        if (isupper((text)[i]))
            text.insert(i," ");"
instead, however it doesn't do anything if I just leave i blank, if I add +1 I get the same issue, if I add -1 it will be out of range and crash the program for sure. If I write +0 to "fool" it, its just the same as writing i.

When I previously used insert outside of the for loop it add it right before the capital letter however just for the first sentence. Im getting confused here.